# WCF service, launch a task every X hours

Tags: multithreading, wcf, timer

I have a WCF service which needs to perform some actions on database every 1 hour and also needs to generate a file with some information.

So which is better, do it through a timer or thread?

The problem of thread would be the constant iteration (with a little delay) on a loop checking if the time has elapsed and if so do the action.

Any ideas on how to achieve this scenario the most efficient possible?

Comment: I have implement something like this throught thread. It is working since January and works ok till now.

Comment: have a look at http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @kostasch.Could you paste if you can  a piece of code? to see how you manage the thread to perform the long task every x hours? Do you use thread.sleep(x) after performing the long task into the infinite loop where x is the time to be elapsed before performing the task again?

Comment: Does the WCF Service do anything besides perform hourly transactions on the database and generate a file?  If not, then I don't see a reason to use WCF at all - a Windows Service would be more suited to something like this, as Uriil put in his answer.

Comment: I wouldn't even go as far as to use a windows service. This sounds like a perfect candidate for a scheduled task, and a console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need long running service.

WCF by it self not good solution.

You should look [at Windows Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample) or [WCF + WF hosted in app fabric](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wf4BatchJob)

One of the reasongs, WCF does not support autostart, so you will have to start it every time after pool recycle(if you host in IIS, or any other hosting process)